# Error ‘Not able to connect to search service to retrieve valid settings’ when launching Query Builder in Central Administration

Tags: search

I have SP2013 foundation version. I am trying to create a result source but when I click on "Launch Query Builder", I am getting the following error :

> "Not able to connect to search service to retrieve valid settings" when launching Query Builder in Central Administration

I have tried the following:

- Give Administrator rights for the Search Service Application to the corresponding user (in Central Administration GUI or over PowersShell Commands)
- Check if the Search Service Application is associated as a service connection to the Central Administration web application.

Comment: Can you check if the user which is trying to launch Query builder is Admin of Search Service Application?

Comment: yes user having full control and administrative privileges.

Comment: I found in my case it was because I had two search service applications, deleted one and the query builder began working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try executing the following command in SharePoint Server 2013 Management Shell as administrator and test the issue again:

```
Enable-SPFeature SearchWebParts -url http://<central admin url>
```

Comment: i already active this feature from central administrator. please confirm me i am having sp 2013 foundation version so its is possible to run search service application on foundation version.